# Solving angular momentum conservation with energy conservation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

A kid of mass M stands at the edge of a platform of radius R which can be freely rotated about its axis. The moment of inertia of the platform is I. The system is at rest when a friend throws a ball of mass m and the kid catches it. If the velocity of the ball is v horizontally along the tangent to the edge of the platform when it was caught by the kid, find the angular speed of the  platform after the event. **Solve using energy conservation**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this question can be likened to a homework type question there is an important idea embedded in it, in that the act of catching is an inelastic collision so kinetic energy will not be conserved.  This means that although energy will be conserved, kinetic energy would not, so it would be extremely difficult, if not impossible(?), to solve this problem using energy conservation.